# Custom Vision on HoloLens

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, hololens, windows-machine-learning

I'm using custom Vision ( https://www.customvision.ai ) to train a model for object recognition. After 10 Iterations of training it suddenly stopped loading. I always export it as onnx and load it on the HoloLens (with this tutorial: https://mtaulty.com/2018/03/29/third-experiment-with-image-classification-on-windows-ml-from-uwp-on-hololens-in-unity/ ). And it worked for quite some time (though the results weren't perfect), but after I continued to train the model to find the things better it simply stopped working.

My Scripts are pretty much like the ones in the Tutorial, just with my Tags and some different names. MainScript.cs https://pastebin.com/hxLrjXqv - my detect.cs (like the daschund.cs in the tutorial) https://pastebin.com/sP4PWNV6

So I deleted my project on Custom Vision and started trained my model from the ground up again. Only have like 40 pictures for 2 Tags with Multiclass (Single tag per image). I only want to know if there is a pointing finger in the picture or not. When deploying on the HoloLens it doesn't get over the line in MainScript

```
LearningModelEvaluationResultPreview evalResult = await learningModel.EvaluateAsync(binding, string.Empty);
```

I don't know what's the problem. If anyone has an idea how to fix it or a different source for how to learn how to run an Object Recognition Model on the HoloLens I would be happy.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Having a similar problem in UWP.  First time I've tried it for me, but if I use other models provided from various open source samples, it works fine, but with my model, exported today as ONNX, it trips up on that same line you note with a not very useful `Exception from HRESULT: 0x88900105`.

Comment: For me even the working model in the tutorial repeatedly throw exceptions, that's why I didn't add them here. I'm very clueless at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom Vision service updated to allow download of ONNX v1.2 models.  Solved my issue.

Comment: Hey, do you use the Insider Preview builds? I think I can't run the model on my HoloLens because of that. I will try to stay at onnx1.0 for now.

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to the subscription level you are using.  You subscription will limit the number of models you can have in storage as a result of training. You subscription is probably limiting you to retaining 10 iterations at a time.

If you go into the CustomVision.AI portal and look at your project, click on Performance tab and you will see all of your training iterations.  Delete the oldest one and I suspect you will be able to train your model again, if I understand your problem correctly.

Comment: I'm sorry if my question was confusing to you. I know the limitations of the trial version and I never hit the 10 iteration maximum. The problem for me was never not being able to train or test the model on the website, but for some reason exported models don't work anymore, while it did before. And the model from the linked blog post works, too. And I don't know what to do anymore since even deleting and retraining the model from scratch doesn't solve anything.

Comment: Ahhh.. I see.  Yes - I am experiencing the same thing right now with custom vision models as well, though I only started to see this problem when I upgrade my dev machine to the Windows Octoboer 2018 release.  In my case, I think it is a mismatch in ONNX model version and the supported ONNX version in WinML.  The latest OS release only supports v1.2 ONNX models and I suspect (have not verified) that the Custom Vision models are older than that.  Still working to see if I am right so no answer for now