# onnx 1.2 models (Custom Vision) on HoloLens

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, hololens, onnx, microsoft-custom-vision

This is a more specific continuation of my previous Post: [Custom Vision on HoloLens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52555299/custom-vision-on-hololens)

I'm still using the Unity Project from this blogpost: https://mtaulty.com/2018/03/29/third-experiment-with-image-classification-on-windows-ml-from-uwp-on-hololens-in-unity/

I had issues that my own exported models don't work with the the code at some point. Now it is possible to export onnx models of version 1.2, but the the old code seems to not be compatible with the new version.

in the line `var evalOutput = await this.learningModel.EvaluateAsync(this.inputData);` in the MainScript it throws `The binding is incomplete or does not match the input/output description. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x88900002)`

Does someone know what I need to change so it works with the new version on HoloLens? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I always thought you only need the new Windows SDK, but it seems I actually need to update the PC and the HoloLens to build 17738. So I misread.

Answer (score 4):

You can find a similar question here: [Windows ML's OS requirement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52642423/windows-mls-os-requirement)
In summary, you are right about needing to update the PC and the Hololens, but the build number you need is 17763 to be on the production version of RS5.

You could also be hitting this issue: [Cannot load model using WinML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656054/cannot-load-model-using-winml)
where the binding isn't quite setup properly.

If you're still having issues, please post the SDK and OS version you're on, as well as the ONNX model version.

Comment: Please include more content here, outside the links